# How to delete files if a numerical part of their name is greater than a given number?

Tags: files, find, rm

I've got files like this:

```
cap_20151023T122915_791033959.png
cap_20151023T122918_946392456.png
cap_20151023T122920_227637228.png
cap_20151023T122920_875467456.png
```

and I would like to use the `find` command to delete those greater than, for example, `cap_20151023T122919*`, which would result in the deletion of `cap_20151023T122920_227637228.png` and `cap_20151023T122920_875467456.png`.

Is there any way to do this, preferably with a single `find` command?

Comment: when I am in need complex deletion, I `ls > x` ; `vi x` to delete from x file I **keep**, then `rm $(< x)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `zsh` and `<[x]-[y]>` *glob operator* (matches numbers in the range `x` to `y`, inclusive; either of the numbers may be omitted to make the range open-ended) e.g.:

```
print -rl -- **/cap_20151023T<122920->_*
```

or, if you want to select only the file names in the `122920-999999` range:

```
print -rl -- **/cap_20151023T<122920-999999>_*
```

so with file names like:

```
tmp/cap_20151023T122915_791033959.png
tmp/cap_20151023T122915791_959.png
tmp/cap_20151023T122918_946392456.png
tmp/cap_20151023T122920_227637228.png
tmp/cap_20151023T1229205_875467456.png
tmp/cap_20151023T122920_875467456.png
tmp/cap_20151023T122980_227637228.png
```

the first one prints:

```
tmp/cap_20151023T122915791_959.png
tmp/cap_20151023T122920_227637228.png
tmp/cap_20151023T1229205_875467456.png
tmp/cap_20151023T122920_875467456.png
tmp/cap_20151023T122980_227637228.png
```

while the second one prints:

```
tmp/cap_20151023T122920_227637228.png
tmp/cap_20151023T122920_875467456.png
tmp/cap_20151023T122980_227637228.png
```

---

If you're happy with the result replace `print -rl` with `rm -f`

Answer (score 0):

it's not optimal, but this will do it:

```
find /where/is/search/folder -name "cap_20151023T1229[2-9]*" -exec rm '{}' \;
```

just replace the numbers in brackets for what you need to delete and change the position as you need.